# Как настроить XAMPP для работы на двух платформах win и osx

Tags: веб-сервер, xampp

Задача: есть внешний hdd, и два компа один на винде один на osx. Помогите настроить xampp так, чтобы на винде и оси использовалась одна папка с проектами. То есть чтобы возможно было переносить внешний диск с проектами с мака на винду, запускать веб сервер и продолжать работу. На маке стоит таксерра для работы с диском. Но я не могу найти где настраивать папку с проектом или изменить папку по умолчанию. Помогите советом.

Comment: симлинк бы лучше сделали на папку с проектом в директории доменов на обоих компах

Comment: @teran спасибо за отклик, не могли бы вы подробнее описать данный метод?

Comment: @teran если вы имеете ввиду типо псевдонима, то он не работает

Comment: имел в виду команду `mklink` в винде, но судя описанию https://habr.com/ru/post/439994/ достаточно просто настроить виртуал хост, указав нужный путь.

Comment: @teran да, тоже нашел инфу про настройку виртуального хоста, единственное, что пока не понятно, как указать путь до базы данных?

Comment: вы про то, что базу надо с собой таскать на диске тоже?

Comment: @teran да, полностью проекты все переносные

Comment: тогда ковыряйте конфиг mysql, там тоже должна настраиваться директория хранения баз. запускать xampp придется видимо уже после подключения диска.

Comment: спасибо, буду ковырять!

Comment: @teran файл конфиг нашел, но меняя пути я лишь получаю не рабочий mysql